# ConstraintSet clone crash

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to clone the ConstraintSet like:

```
        ConstraintLayout cl = findViewById(R.id.mainActivityParentCl);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(cl);
```

It crashes on clone(cl),

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet
```

It doesnt crash when using

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

It crashes on 1.1.3:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Solution?

Comment: did you did what error message is suggesting to do?

Comment: give id to every views in xml file

Comment: @VivekMishra it didnt seem related, but it worked.

Comment: +1 because the error message alone helped me with my issue. I should check those more often. Thanks for posting. My issue: I assumed that generateViewId() also set it - it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're facing is because from `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0` it is necessary to give id to each view as because when doing the XML part of things via Java/Kotlin code and when especially cloning layout(s) using `ConstraintSet` which can be further used to create dynamic views, which can be created easily; whose id if not given, gives or throws an exception (at the time of cloning the constraintSet) as yours as because when the `ConstraintLayout` is redrawn (like in case, when the App goes to background and is then resumed) this exception is triggered (due to lack of the view's accessibility whose id is not given). And as per the Android Developers' guidelines as well you must provide a unique id to each and every view to have proper accessibility to that view.

I hope, this helps you.